# RPi2 PsSession: "Command 'iotstartup' cannot be found"

Tags: powershell, iot, raspberry-pi2

I am in the process of deploying a Windows Universal App to my Raspberry Pi 2.
I am following a very handy guide published [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm).

Everything's fine but I get a peculiar warning when trying to run the `iotstartup` command after having established the `PsSession`.

[image: ps snippet]

If I simply press return again, the message disappears and the command seems to work fine...

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is it a known powershell thing, or has something gone awry on my device?   (If it's of any significance, I had to re-flash the OS once or twice in order to get anything to deploy remotely).

I hope it's not my device; but I would be interested to hear of any clarification on this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iotstartup as setcomputername are executables. Use the invoke command, see this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).

```
& iotstartup list
```

will do.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get when I try to pick up about five unfamiliar technologies at once!